# Dealing with Empty Brackets in a List

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a large list with varying constituent parts. Some of these are like this:

i.e. `graphlist[[34]]`

```
{{{33, 0.0115084}}, {{33, 0.00539003}}, {{33, 0.0158185}}, 
 {{33, 0.0136278}}, {{33, 0.00756737}}, {{33, 0.0017506}}, 
 {{33, 0.038599}}, {{33, 0.00538894}}, {{33, 0.00656522}},
 {{33, 0.00310004}}, {{33, 0.00151645}}, {{33, 7.75*10^-7}},
 {{33, 0.00205609}}, {{33, 0.00125328}}}
```

Whereas others are like this:

`graphlist[[1]]`

```
{{}, {{0, 0.00342769}}, {{0, 0.00503465}}, {}, 
 {{0, 0.000187}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}
```

Because they are all part of a long list, I'm trying to find a command that can do the following. On a list without any null values, I am running this command to get the second part:

```
graphlist[[34]][[All, 1]][[All, 2]]

> {0.0115084, 0.00539003, 0.0158185, 0.0136278, 0.00756737, 0.0017506, 
> 0.038599, 0.00538894, 0.00656522, 0.00310004, 0.00151645, 
>  7.75*10^-7, 0.00205609, 0.00125328}
```

But if I run a similar command on the list with nulls, the error message: "Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>" ensues. My goal is to similarly get output that would look like this:

> {0,0.00342769,0.00503465,0,0.000187,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

Is there a way to construct a command that simply returns a 'zero' value for empty brackets? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "My goal is to similarly get output that would look like this" are the values in your final example second elements?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Sorry, I should have been specific - they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
l1 = {{{33, 0.0115084}}, {{33, 0.00539003}}, {{33, 0.0158185}}, {{33, 
     0.0136278}}, {{33, 0.00756737}}, {{33, 0.0017506}}, {{33, 
     0.038599}}, {{33, 0.00538894}}, {{33, 0.00656522}}, {{33, 
     0.00310004}}, {{33, 0.00151645}}, {{33, 7.75*10^-7}}, {{33, 
     0.00205609}}, {{33, 0.00125328}}};
l2 = {{}, {{0, 0.00342769}}, {{0, 0.00503465}}, {}, {{0, 
     0.000187}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}};
```

you can do this:

```
If[# === {}, 0, #[[1, 2]]] & /@ l1
{0.0115084, 0.00539003, 0.0158185, 0.0136278, 0.00756737, 0.0017506, 0.038599, 0.00538894, 0.00656522, 0.00310004, 0.00151645, 7.75*10^-7, 0.00205609, 0.00125328}


If[# === {}, 0, #[[1, 2]]] & /@ l2
{0, 0.00342769, 0.00503465, 0, 0.000187, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you wish to get rid of the `{}`, then Mike's answer using `DeleteCases` works in this particular case, but will fail in general, because it will not remove `{}` that's nested deeper (such as `{{}}`). Using `ReplaceAll` or `/.` also fails in some cases because it removes it from inside any head. For example, if you have `{a, {}, {{}}, f[b, {}]}`, the expected behaviour is to not remove the `{}` from inside `f`. The proper way to do it, as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6563973) on Stack Overflow is:

```
expr = {a, {}, {{}}, f[b, {}]};
Replace[expr, x_List :> DeleteCases[x, {}], {0, Infinity}]
(* {a, f[b, {}]} *)
```

So for your expression in `graphlist[[1]]`, it would give:

```
Replace[graphlist[[1]], x_List :> DeleteCases[x, {}], {0, Infinity}]
(* {{{0, 0.00342769}}, {{0, 0.00503465}}, {{0, 0.000187}}} *)
```

*EDIT*

An alternative using `ReplaceAll` could be

```
expr /. {i : Except[_List] :> i, l_ /; Flatten[l] === {} :> Sequence[]}
```

or more compactly using `ReplaceRepeated` (probably not as efficient)

```
expr //. {i : Except[_List] :> i, {} :> Sequence[]}
```

Comment: I like yours best, but it can be done properly with `ReplaceAll` too. `expr /. {i : Except[_List] :> i, 
  l_ /; Flatten[l] === {} :> Sequence[]}`

Comment: @Rojo I like it! More than mine, actually. I was referring to `/. {} -> Sequence[]` in that statement though. I think yours is more reasonable in this corner case:  `expr = {{}, a, {{}}, f[{{{}}}]}`. "Reasonable" of course depends on the intent — the objective in the linked question was to remove all `{}` if it is inside another list, which mine does, but I think I would intuitively expect the behaviour in yours. Feel free to edit it into my answer (or if you write a new one, I'll upvote it)

Answer (score 6):

```
l = {{}, {{0, 0.00342769}}, {{0, 0.00503465}}, {}, {{0, 0.000187}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}
List /@ Sequence @@@ l
(*
-> {{{0, 0.00342769}}, {{0, 0.00503465}}, {{0, 0.000187}}}
*)
```

Or

```
l /. {} -> 0
(*
{0, {{0, 0.00342769}}, {{0, 0.00503465}}, 0, {{0, 0.000187}}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
*)
```

Or

```
Last /@ Sequence @@@ (l /. {} -> {{0}})
(*
-> {0, 0.00342769, 0.00503465, 0, 0.000187, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
*)
```

Depending on what you really want as a result :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not delete the {} before carrying out any further analysis?

```
newgraphlist = 
 DeleteCases[{{}, {{0, 0.00342769}}, {{0, 0.00503465}}, {}, {{0, 
     0.000187}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}, {}]
```

...but if you want zeros then you can use a rule replacement

```
graphlist /. {} -> 0
```

In your final example it looks like you are taking all the second elements so

```
newgraphlist = graphlist /. {} -> {{0, 0}}
newgraphlist[[All, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

With

```
list = {{}, {{0, 0.00342769`}}, {{0, 0.00503465`}}, {}, {{0, 0.000187`}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}};
```

Several alternatives in addition to previous answers:

```
Last @@@ (list /. {} -> {{0, 0}})
```

gives

```
(* {0, 0.00342769, 0.00503465, 0, 0.000187, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

So do

```
list //. {{} -> {{0, 0}}, {{_, x_}} :> x}
```

and

```
Replace[list, {{} -> 0, {{_, x_}} :> x}, {1}]
```

the latter thanks to Mr.Wizard.

Comment: You would do better to use: `Replace[list, {{} -> 0, {{_, x_}} :> x}, {1}]` -- this way you only scan the list once.  You should use `:>` for named patterns on the RHS.  +1 nevertheless

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, great point. And thank you for the vote.